# Telling applications to open and then to quit isn't working properly on applescript

Tags: applescript, tell

This script is to open microsoft apps and then quit after 3 seconds

```
tell application "Finder"
set myFolder to ((startup disk as text) & "Applications:Microsoft Office 2011") as alias
set myFiles to (every item of myFolder) as alias list
open myFiles
end tell

delay 3

tell application "System Events" to set the visible of every process to true

set white_list to {"Finder"}

try
    tell application "Finder"
        set process_list to the name of every process whose visible is true
    end tell
    repeat with i from 1 to (number of items in process_list)
        set this_process to item i of the process_list
        if this_process is not in white_list then
            tell application this_process
                quit
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
on error
    tell the current application to display dialog "An error has occurred!" & return & "This script will now quit" buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with icon 0
end try
end tell
```

but when I run the script, it stops after this.  (EDIT) it seems to close every app besides the microsoft applications

```
tell application "Finder"
set myFolder to ((startup disk as text) & "Applications:Microsoft Office 2011") as alias
set myFiles to (every item of myFolder) as alias list
open myFiles
```

Both opening and closing the applications scripts work great separately but I don't seem to know how to join them. If anyone knows why this is happening, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: How do you know it stops after “open myFiles”? *delay 3* has no visible effects. You might try putting some *display dialog "Hello 1"*, etc., into the script to see exactly where it stops.

Comment: hmm well display dialog works after "open myFiles" but the reason i know it stops is because when i run the script, soon after "open myFiles" the applescript toolbar with the "Record, stop, run, compile" buttons are back to the way it looks when you haven't run the script yet (sorry i don't really know how to explain that well, hope you understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that telling Finder to open an app is asyncrynous in the script. Meaning, it won't finish until the app is loaded before moving on. You're never gonna get it right with the delay command, either. I'd suggest using 'tell app xxx to activate' which does wait before proceeding. And, it makes your script way cleaner.

```
property myApps : {"Microsoft Word", "Microsoft Excel"}

repeat with thisApp in myApps
    try
        tell application thisApp to activate
    end try
end repeat

-- do whatever you need after all are open

repeat with thisApp in myApps
    try
        tell application thisApp to quit
    end try
end repeat
```

If you are wanting to quit every visible app except Finder, you can also add

```
tell application "Finder" to set myApps to name of (every process whose ((visible is true) and (name is not "Finder")))
```

Comment: i'll try it and let you know, thanks for helping out a new learner :) with all the other questions i've asked, appreciate it

Comment: so do I need to type all the applications that I want to open inside `property myApps : {"applications to open"}`

 and also where would I add 

`tell APPLICATION "Finder" to set myApps to name of (every process whose ((visible is true) and (name is not "Finder")))`

Comment: Yes, all you need is the app names, each is surrounded in quotes, with a comma separating each. Such as   {"Microsoft Word", "Microsoft Excel", "Microsoft Powerpoint", "Microsoft Outlook"}

Comment: I'm not following you. What are all the app you want to start and quit? I'll edit the script if you tell me the names.

Comment: well pretty much any app inside the Applications folder of startup disk, i'm just testing something out

Comment: You want the script to launch every application in the /Applications folder? That's not a good idea. You can have a script to look for every application within a given folder, recursively. You can google for a recurse search in a folder.

Comment: oh not all the apps, just some, and yea sorry, not sure where i actually put the code

`tell APPLICATION "Finder" to set myApps to name of (every process whose ((visible is true) and (name is not "Finder")))`

Comment: that can go before the second repeat loop to redefine myApps as all open apps.